# Breakpoint in code executed by exec()

Tags: python, debugging

I use exec() to run a piece of python code in my main python application. The debugger doesn't stop at a breakpoint which is placed in the piece of code executed by exec().

Is this possible?

Comment: If you have your code in the file system, why do you run it with `exec`?

Comment: Klaus D imply the code executed from files are usually done so using `ìmport` in which case breakpoints should work fine. If your code is generated or read dynamically, then you won't be able to set a debugger breakpoint AFAIK.